# What's the difference of the two systems?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I've lately been working on a piston door in Minecraft. It is almost finished and the only part that I have to add is the redstone signal elevator, but then it does something that leaves me confused.
Here are two picture of the systems, which normally should be giving the same result.

The first one is the one which works...

[image]

And the second one won't work.

[image]

Both are powered by a button (it is necessary).

**Here's the question: Is this a bug or it is normal? And if yes, normal, why?**

Comment: Adding a world download link would be potentially helpful here, could you include it? Thanks!

Comment: I have absolutely no ideas how to do this

Comment: To provide a world download link, find the world in `/.minecraft/saves`, place it in a zip archive and upload to google drive, dropbox or any other online storage. Then just provide a link.

Comment: Your pictures don't even show what's not working... your pictures are exactly the same except for the button vs torches, and they are currently giving the same result in the pictures.

Comment: Had you even tried it in your own world? By the way I found the answer myself :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so finally I found the reason by myself.

Before I start to explain, I forgot to say that that machine was supposed to do: displace or drag back the block in a location, and to avoid the observer block doing an entire mess, we have to retract the pistons in a specific order.

To make them retract in a specific order, I had to use a comparator. The thing is that the comparator compare which side's signal is the strongest, and if they are the same, it will let the signal pass, which is EXACTLY what I DON'T want.

So what I had to do is simply to switch the comparator from compare to sustract mode, since 15-15=0.

PS: Because the problem is solved, I won't put a world download.